# Can anyone share a chinese supported pdf template sample

Tags: pdf-generation, adobe, cjk

Is there anything we need to change on pdf template level to support Chinese or Japanese . I am using a fillable template. While writing it with my pdf library(using tcpdf) it is giving some garbled text. While copy pasting Chinese text to this template field also gives some squares where as English is filling perfectly. Does anyone out there have a sample fillable pdf template that supports Chinese to share?

Answer (score 0):

generally you need to embed font to properly display foreign characters in a PDF. I've not tried using tcpdf but saw posts that say embedding a TTF (true type font) of the correct language seems to do the trick.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.